Issue in Accessing Spacy Models from Hugging Face
I had uploaded my NER model trained through Spacy on huggingface. While trying to inference, I am facing this issue:
pip install https://huggingface.co/JeswinMS4/en_resume_pipeline/resolve/main/en_resume_pipeline-any-py3-none-any.whl


ERROR: Invalid requirement: 'en-resume-pipeline==any': Expected end or
semicolon (after name and no valid version specifier)
en-resume-pipeline==any
^

The documentation also states this way to load. Is there anything I am missing out?
